# How to open the Facebook like button confirmation dialog in App instead of the browser?

Tags: html, facebook

I'm trying to implement a facebook like button for my Facebook page.

In WEB desktop it works without a problem:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/barackobama" data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-share="true"></div>
```

But in mobile WEB the facebook like confirmation dialogue opens in the browser instead of the facebook android APP.

*I have tried using the fb:// scheme combined with the facebook page ID, but it's not working*

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="fb://page/6815841748" data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-share="true"></div>
```

Any ideas how to achieve that ?

Thank you.